# Non-linear ODE with diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

I have a differential equation of this form:

$\frac{dX}{dr}(r)$= M(r)X(r)$ + (\sum_{i}X_i) D(r)X(r)$

$X(r)$ is a size n vector.

$M(r)$ and $D(r)$ are n x n matrices with $D(r)$ diagonal. They are both well known for any value of r.

My boundary condition is $\frac{dX}{dr}(0)=0$

I could solve this equation analytically if I did not have this non linear component introduced by the sum of $X_i$ looking for the eigenvalues and eigen vectors of M for any r . One way I thought about was to solve it without it (just solve X' = MX) and then re-injecting the values I found for $\sum_{i}X_i$ and treat is as a function of $r$ only to solve the full equation. Do it iteratively until X(r) converges.

Are you aware of any other methods that would be more efficient than this one ?

Thank you